# What is the purpose of col-lg-12 in Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I saw a video where the author will just use

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
     some content
</div>
```

inside of a `div.container` and a `div.row`.  What is the purpose of that, if that is the only item in the row?  I thought if you want something to occupy a whole row, you might just list it as `col-xs-12` so that it will affect all screen sizes.  But if it is the only item, then won't it just automatically occupy all 12 columns? So why use that and why use `lg`?

Comment: col-lg-12 means that in large devices it should occupy all the space.
the following means that it should occupy all the space in large devices and half of the space in medium sized devices.

`<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-6
">Some Text</div>`

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
  some content
</div>
```

This basically means that the div should acquire entire width, when the page is being displayed on large devices(according to official documentation, devices with max-width of 1200px).

To understand this better, if you had to display the same div on say smaller screens for half the width then you would write as below:

```
 <div class="col-xs-6">
   some content
 </div>
```

or

```
  <div class="col-lg-12 col-xs-6">
   some content
  </div>
```

(note: both the above codes have the same end result).

Similarly if you want you can specify how your divisions should be displayed for smaller as well as medium devices.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

It's simply for consistency sake. `.col-xs-12` and `.col-xl-12` will appear visual identical regardless of viewport.

Answer (score 0):

Grid system is nothing else than the width of a `div` for a particular screen width. And this width comes into effect when the content of the block exceeds the width that is was suppose to occupy.

`div width` along with `media queries` is what actually these `col-*-*` are. So `col-lg-*` comes into play when your screen width is more than 1200px. But having said that if your content is a single line it doesn't matter what `col-*-12` you use.

Suppose you have a single line in your entire HTML page and you always want it to be 100%. So if wont want matter if you place it inside a `col-xs-12`or `col-sm-12` or `col-md-12` or `col-lg-12`. They all will occupy `width:100%`.

Grid system only provides ease of responsive web developement nothing else. Even you can define your own grid system.

Suppose you combine this `col-lg-12` width another class of `col-md-6` then for screen width less than 1200px it would only occupy 50% of the page width. Similarly for other classes, just a way to align and stack your content for your responsive web design.

Hope this helps.

Comment: so if it is just one item in the row, and this is the only `col-*-*` class, then the `col-*-*` is not needed?

Comment: If there is a single item like a `para` tag and you want the content to be `width:100%` then in that case no `col-*-*` class is needed. It will behave the same way as any `col-*-12` would (except some gutter spacing - padding, margin).
Check this https://plnkr.co/edit/ECrFEXgBafZbzbdaEoti?p=preview
You will see that all `col-*-12` and a single `para` tag occupy 100% width.

Comment: A `container` is added to make content more symetrical (width is generally set at 70% with margin: 0 auto). So this makes content always within some margin and more aligned thats all.
And for `row` class, it is generally used when you are building column in a grid.